# I am using ckeditor for my mail merge having an issue when i am trying to disable only specific paragraph in the text area

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

So what i am trying to achieve is that when any user is trying to access the Ckeditor Text area there will be some text which is disabled for use to modify but he can edit some text, and he can add more text if he wants in the white space i am also using Mail merge in my code so you can skip ckeditor.on('dialogDefinition') fiction

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Using placeholders</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" data-sample-short>&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href=&quot;https://ckeditor.com/&quot;&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
<p contenteditable="false">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</p>

<p class="a">
  This text can be edited by the user. aa
</p>


    <p contenteditable="false">
            This text can be edited by the user.
        </p>

</textarea>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
            height: 220,
            readOnly:true
    });




        CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(event) {
  if ('placeholder' == event.data.name) {
    var input = event.data.definition.getContents('info').get('name');
    input.type = 'select';
    input.items = [ ['Company'], ['Email'], ['First Name'], ['Last Name'] ];
    input.setup = function() {
      this.setValue('Company');
    };
  }
});

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using the placeholder plugin.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder 
When you click "Download" a modal appears. At the bottom it shows the Add-on dependencies which also need to be uploaded to the plugin directory. Each Add-on may also require it's own dependencies.

```
// example in config.js
config.extraPlugins = "placeholder,widget,lineutils,dialog,clipboard, ... {plus-other-dependent-plugins-as-needed}";
```

More than one extraPlugins are added comma separated.